# I have an MD5 encrypted link. How do I decrypt?

Tags: hash, md5

I have this MD5 hash of a link:

```
687474703a2f2f696d6775722e636f6d2f45554a43734742
```

I only have this code, no other information. How can I crack it?

Comment: [That's not an MD5 hash](http://imgur.com/EUJCsGB).

Comment: John Deters and grc have already answered the quesiton, but I'd like to note that MD5 can't be decrypted, as any cryptographic hash function, MD5 is a one direction function. Through reverse tables you may be able to get a possible value that generates that MD5 but there are infinit values that generate the same hash

Answer (score 19):

It's not MD5 (which is a message digest algorithm, not an encryption algorithm), and it's not even base 64. It's just ASCII encoded as hex.  It contains

```
http://imgur.com/EUJCsGB
```

which is a link to an image of a bird. The image was uploaded by someone named MD5, that's as close as it gets.